# unbale to form proper join query in spring data jpa using @Query in Reporsitory

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring Data Jpa and able to get the result using proper function names on a single table. But now I am facing problem to get the result based on join. I have two tables Invoice Table (columns : accountNumber, courierId), Account Table (columns : number, clinetId). Now I need to join these two tables and get Invoice results based on courierId and clientId. So in the repository I have formed the query as shown below:

```
@Query("select Invoice from Invoice i left join Account a on i.accountNumber = a.number where i.courierId=?1 and a.clientId=?2")    
    List<Invoice> findByCourierIdAndClientId(Long courierId, Long clientId);
```

But I am getting the following error in my debugging log:

```
[ERROR] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter -  Path expected for join!
[ERROR] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter -  Path expected for join!
antlr.SemanticException: Path expected for join!

[ERROR] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter -  Invalid path: 'a.clientId'
[ERROR] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter -  Invalid path: 'a.clientId'
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.InvalidPathException: Invalid path: 'a.clientId'

[ERROR] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter -  left-hand operand of a binary operator was null
[ERROR] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter -  left-hand operand of a binary operator was null
antlr.SemanticException: left-hand operand of a binary operator was null
```

In Account Table I have client_id field in mysql table and in Account.java, I have

```
@ManyToOne
private Client client;

public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }
```

if I use the suggested solution,

```
@Query("SELECT i from Invoice i WHERE i.courierId =?1 AND i.clientId =?2")
List<Invoice> findByCourierIdAndClientId(Long courierId, Long clientId);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: clientId of: com.trace.domain.Invoice [SELECT i from com.trace.domain.Invoice i WHERE i.courierId =?1 AND i.clientId =?2]
```

The following are my mappings:

In Account.java,

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
 @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
 private Set<Invoice> invoices = new HashSet<>();
```

And in Invoice.java,

```
 @ManyToOne   
 private Account account;
```

Is there any changes I need to make in these mappings. Moreover in the solution

```
@Query("SELECT i from Invoice i WHERE i.courierId =?1 AND i.clientId =?2")
```

I don't follow how invoice table is gets only the joined details with Account, moreover there is no `i.clientId` in Invoice Table. `clientId` is present in Account Table only.

The following is my Invoice.java

```
/**
 * A Invoice.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Invoice implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "account_number")
    private String accountNumber;

    @Column(name = "invoice_number")
    private String invoiceNumber;

    @Column(name = "invoice_amount")
    private Double invoiceAmount;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "edi_number")
    private String ediNumber;

    @Column(name = "bill_date")
    private Date billDate;

    @Column(name = "courier_id")
    private Long courierId;

 // @JoinColumn(name="owner_id", nullable=false)

    @ManyToOne   
    private Account account;



    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoice")
    //@JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<InvoiceDetails> invoiceDetailss = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    public String getInvoiceNumber() {
        return invoiceNumber;
    }

    public void setInvoiceNumber(String invoiceNumber) {
        this.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
    }

    public Double getInvoiceAmount() {
        return invoiceAmount;
    }

    public void setInvoiceAmount(Double invoiceAmount) {
        this.invoiceAmount = invoiceAmount;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getEdiNumber() {
        return ediNumber;
    }

    public void setEdiNumber(String ediNumber) {
        this.ediNumber = ediNumber;
    }


        public Date getBillDate() {
            return billDate;
        }

        public void setBillDate(Date billDate) {
            this.billDate = billDate;
        }

        public Long getCourierId() {
            return courierId;
        }

        public void setCourierId(Long courierId) {
            this.courierId = courierId;
        }

        public Account getAccount() {
            return account;
        }

        public void setAccount(Account account) {
            this.account = account;
        }

    public Set<InvoiceDetails> getInvoiceDetailss() {
        return invoiceDetailss;
    }

    public void setInvoiceDetailss(Set<InvoiceDetails> invoiceDetailss) {
        this.invoiceDetailss = invoiceDetailss;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        Invoice invoice = (Invoice) o;

        if ( ! Objects.equals(id, invoice.id)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Invoice{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", accountNumber='" + accountNumber + "'" +
                ", invoiceNumber='" + invoiceNumber + "'" +
                ", invoiceAmount='" + invoiceAmount + "'" +
                ", ediNumber='" + ediNumber + "'" +
                ", status='" + status + "'" +
                ", billDate='" + billDate + "'" +
                ", courierId='" + courierId + "'" +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And the following is my Account.java,

```
/**
 * Account.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Account implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "number", nullable = false)
    private String number;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "currency_code")
    private String currencyCode;

    @Column(name = "edi_type")
    private String ediType;

    @Column(name = "is_fedex_express_gsr")
    private Boolean isFedexExpressGsr;

    @Column(name = "is_fedex_ground_gsr")
    private Boolean isFedexGroundGsr;

    @Column(name = "is_ups_gsr")
    private Boolean isUpsGsr;

    @Column(name = "electronic_voiding")
    private Boolean electronicVoiding;

    @Column(name = "activate_signature_service")
    private Boolean activateSignatureService;

    @Column(name = "reject_invoices")
    private Boolean rejectInvoices;

    @Column(name = "notify_client_services")
    private Boolean notifyClientServices;

    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private Boolean isActive;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "state")
    private String state;

    @Column(name = "postal_code")
    private String postalCode;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Invoice> invoices = new HashSet<>();



    @ManyToOne
    private Courier courier;

    @ManyToOne
    private Client client;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "account_group_members",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "account_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<AccountGroup> accountGroups = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCurrencyCode() {
        return currencyCode;
    }

    public void setCurrencyCode(String currencyCode) {
        this.currencyCode = currencyCode;
    }

    public String getEdiType() {
        return ediType;
    }

    public void setEdiType(String ediType) {
        this.ediType = ediType;
    }

    public Boolean getIsFedexExpressGsr() {
        return isFedexExpressGsr;
    }

    public void setIsFedexExpressGsr(Boolean isFedexExpressGsr) {
        this.isFedexExpressGsr = isFedexExpressGsr;
    }

    public Boolean getIsFedexGroundGsr() {
        return isFedexGroundGsr;
    }

    public void setIsFedexGroundGsr(Boolean isFedexGroundGsr) {
        this.isFedexGroundGsr = isFedexGroundGsr;
    }

    public Boolean getIsUpsGsr() {
        return isUpsGsr;
    }

    public void setIsUpsGsr(Boolean isUpsGsr) {
        this.isUpsGsr = isUpsGsr;
    }

    public Boolean getElectronicVoiding() {
        return electronicVoiding;
    }

    public void setElectronicVoiding(Boolean electronicVoiding) {
        this.electronicVoiding = electronicVoiding;
    }

    public Boolean getActivateSignatureService() {
        return activateSignatureService;
    }

    public void setActivateSignatureService(Boolean activateSignatureService) {
        this.activateSignatureService = activateSignatureService;
    }

    public Boolean getRejectInvoices() {
        return rejectInvoices;
    }

    public void setRejectInvoices(Boolean rejectInvoices) {
        this.rejectInvoices = rejectInvoices;
    }

    public Boolean getNotifyClientServices() {
        return notifyClientServices;
    }

    public void setNotifyClientServices(Boolean notifyClientServices) {
        this.notifyClientServices = notifyClientServices;
    }

    public Boolean getIsActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setIsActive(Boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }

    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }

    public Courier getCourier() {
        return courier;
    }

    public void setCourier(Courier courier) {
        this.courier = courier;
    }

    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public Set<Invoice> getInvoices() {
        return invoices;
    }

    public void setInvoices(Set<Invoice> invoices) {
        this.invoices = invoices;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        Account shipper = (Account) o;

        if (!Objects.equals(id, shipper.id))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Shipper{" + "id=" + id + ", number='" + number + "'" + ", name='" + name + "'" + ", currencyCode='"
                + currencyCode + "'" + ", ediType='" + ediType + "'" + ", isFedexExpressGsr='" + isFedexExpressGsr + "'"
                + ", isFedexGroundGsr='" + isFedexGroundGsr + "'" + ", isUpsGsr='" + isUpsGsr + "'"
                + ", electronicVoiding='" + electronicVoiding + "'" + ", activateSignatureService='"
                + activateSignatureService + "'" + ", rejectInvoices='" + rejectInvoices + "'"
                + ", notifyClientServices='" + notifyClientServices + "'" + ", isActive='" + isActive + "'"
                + ", address='" + address + "'" + ", city='" + city + "'" + ", state='" + state + "'" + ", postalCode='"
                + postalCode + "'" + '}';
    }
}
```

After making the following entry in InvoiceRepository.java,

```
@Query("from Invoice i " + " where i.courierId = :courierId " + " and i.account.client.id = :clientId ")
    List<Invoice> findByCourierIdAndClientId(@Param("courierId") Long courierId, @Param("clientId") Long clientId);
```

I am not getting any error but I am getting any result set from mysql database. My debugging log is as follows:

```
[DEBUG] com.sample.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Enter: com.sample.web.rest.InvoiceResource.getInvoicesByCourierIdAndClientId() with argument[s] = [1, 1]
[DEBUG] com.sample.web.rest.InvoiceResource - REST request to get Invoices  By Courier Id and Client Id 1  1
[DEBUG] com.sample.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Enter: com.sample.service.InvoiceService.findByCourierIdAndClientId() with argument[s] = [1, 1]
[DEBUG] com.sample.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Exit: com.sample.service.InvoiceService.findByCourierIdAndClientId() with result = []
[DEBUG] com.sample.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Exit: com.sample.web.rest.InvoiceResource.getInvoicesByCourierIdAndClientId() with result = []
```

In InvoiceResource.java, I have the following mapping:

```
// Get Invoices By Courier Id and CustomerId
    @RequestMapping(value = "/invoices/byCourierAndClient", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public List<Invoice> getInvoicesByCourierIdAndClientId(@RequestParam(value = "courierId") Long courierId,
            @RequestParam(value = "clientId") Long clientId) {
        log.debug("REST request to get Invoices  By Courier Id and Client Id " + courierId + "  " + clientId);
        return invoiceService.findByCourierIdAndClientId(courierId, clientId);
    }
```

The Id field in Client.java is as follows:

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
```

The following query I have used to verify my data manually on mysql database tables which is returning result set containing on record.

```
select * from invoice i, account a where i.account_number = a.number
and i.courier_id = 1
and a.client_id = 1
```

Comment: Can you post the exact columns for your invoice entity class?

Comment: I strongly suggest you change your current entity implementation to make full use of Spring/Sprin Data. It looks to me like you're saving data multiple times (e.g. you have a @ManyToOne annotation for your account in invoice but still save the account number separately. After correctly setting it up, you can directly query any object mapped in your entity files. Like Adrian Shum describes in his answer, no join is required and you can even use the default query for your specific case. See: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brief glance on your code seems suggested that you already have proper relationship mapping between `Invoice` and `Account`.  In JPQL/HQL, you do not join like SQL by providing the join criteria.  So your query should be

```
@Query("from Invoice i "
      + " where i.courierId = :courierId "
      + " and i.account.client.id = :clientId ")
List<Invoice> findByCourierIdAndClientId(@Param("courierId") Long courierId, 
                                         @Param("clientId") Long clientId);
```

(Assume the ID field in `Client` is called `id`)

Looks intuitive right?

And, given your query is really straight-forward, you can even let Spring Data generate your query by properly naming your finder method:

```
// no more @Query needed, works magically
List<Invoice> findByCourierIdAndAccountClientId(Long courierId, Long clientId);
```

Comment: Shum, from your answer I can see your solution should work. When I applied this, I am not getting any error but the response is coming as an empty array. I have checked in the mysql database manually through join condition even has result set but I am getting that result set.

Comment: I will suggest you turn on sql logging (by `<property name = "hibernate.show_sql" value = "true" />`, or by using tools like JdbcDsLog) to confirm the actual SQL issued to DB.  Sometimes the generated SQL may be out of expectation due to things mis-mapped.  Though my guts feeling is data problem, like in account you are pointing to a client that is not exists

Comment: Yes, you are right Shum, I turned on show_sql and realized the mistake. The formed query shows  invoice.account_id ... but in my table that field is empty. As Lukehey, pointed out to have another field account_number caused this confusion. Now I am able to get the result correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. If you have the relation mapped correctly (@OneToMany/ManyToOne), you don't need to explicitly join the tables.

```
@Query("SELECT i from Invoice i WHERE i.courierId =?1 AND i.clientId =?2")
List<Invoice> findByCourierIdAndClientId(Long courierId, Long clientId);
```

You can even pass objects to a query directly, e.g.

```
@Query("SELECT i from Invoice i WHERE i.courierId= :courier AND i.clientId = :client")
List<Invoice> findByCourierAndClient(@Param("courier") Courier courier, @Param("client") Client client);
```

Comment: It seems that it does not work. If I use this solution I am getting error. I am editing the question with these details.